# How can I avoid XSD validation of the .bpmn file for WebSphere when starting up the server?

Tags: xsd-validation

How can I avoid XSD validation of the .bpmn file for WebSphere when starting up the server?

My company has the access cut to go out to the internet in servers and the application fails on start up because it can’t validate against the XSD (`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/drools drools.xsd http://www.bpsim.org/schemas/1.0 bpsim.xsd http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd"`) present in .bpmn file.

We whitelisted these URLs for specific server IPs with help of IT support team and it resolved this issue temporarily. This whitelisting is allowed to set for a week only and I have to resolve this issue before that deadline.

Comment: Could it be a viable strategy to reroute the domain name to a network-internal IP that can serve the file? On Windows, you'd use the etc/hosts file, other OS have other mechanisms.